# How to prevent fake form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I have page with simple form. To submit this form I need person submitting to check checkbox (some privacy policy etc).

I have the form like this:

```
<form role="form" class="form" id="zamowienie" action="send_order.php" method="post">
<button type="button" id="wyslijZamowienie">SEND</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="regCheckbox" value="">
</form>
```

(Of course, every distracting inputs are deleted.)
Then I have script that shall submit form only after checking the checkbox.

```
button.on("click",function(){
if ($("#regCheckbox").is(":checked")) $("#zamowienie").submit();
```

Unfortunately, I found out that user can change localy the button type from "button" to "submit" and he will be able to submit the form ignoring my submit protect script.

And additional question. I am not an expert but I started wandering what else can do user with FireBug or dev tools. Can he perform any attacks this way?

Many thanks for any answers or guidance.

Comment: Congratulations! You have discovered why **validation must be done on the server**. JavaScript validation is just a UI bonus.

Comment: There's nothing you can do on the client to prevent this. You have to validate on the server to be totally safe.

Comment: `what else can do user with FireBug or dev tools` They can do anything you can do with JavaScript. As @Juhana says, this is why you ***must*** validate request data on the server too.

Comment: To be sure, client-side JavaScript validation is supposed to be a convenience, saving everyone the time and bandwidth taken up by failed server-side validation. In other words: implement server-side validation **first**, client-side validation second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user is able to change your form in many other ways, not just changing the type attribute of the button, the best is to check it on the server side too, for example, you should do something like this:

#### Validate via Jquery:

```
$("#zamowienie").submit(function(e) {
    if(!$('input[type=checkbox]#regCheckbox:checked').length) {
        //stop the form from submitting
        return false;
    }
    //Continue and submit the form
    return true;
});
```

#### Validate in the backend:

If you are using `PHP` in the backend for example, you have to check if the checkbox is checked, with something like this:
*Note: Your checkbox need a name attribute, let's say `mycheckbox`*

```
if (isset($_POST['mycheckbox'])) {
    //Process your form
}
else{
    //Checkbox was not checked, print an error message or something
}
```

Always validate your code in the backend, the Javascript validation is just a plus for usability and User Experience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't necesarily fully understand why you are validating  it with jquery  the way you do, but I will try to find out :) I understand that i should reopen the form page after I find out that something is wrong with data. Or use Ajax instead instead to prevent page from refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the reasons why you always validate on the server.
There's no problem validating on the FrontEnd, but you need a double check from the server so you guarantee that all the data is as you expected.

As for the Firebug/Chrome Dev Tools question, anyone can pretty much edit everything from your FrontEnd. From CSS to JS. Even if you minify it!

Comment: Yes! Exactly. In Chrome Dev tools one click allows you to render new stylesheet rules. In 3 lines anyone here could change the button's type on the JavaScript console. Easy.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that the user can do everything he wants. He can modify everything in your form or even create another one targeting the same url and create a script to submit it 1000 times.

That's why you often read :

> Never Trust User Input

This means you have to check the whole request on server side : check the method used, check that the fields you are expected are set with data types that you expect.

**To summarize :** Front end is just here to help the "usual" user to communicate with your server, but on server side (back end), you have to expect every input possible.

Comment: Also, that's where recaptcha comes in

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Honestly, I do not want to add any kind of captcha to my form to reduce number of failed submissions (as this is a form to order a product). 
I will try to protect myself from 1000 submissions with some PHP and, but I am not sure how to do that.
I am also planning to validate if any other fields are added to form and submitted - for this I think i have an idea. 
I shall produce some code and ask another question if this is protecting myself from unwanted activity.